# How to traverse files (conditionally) faster than using FileSystemObject

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I've written some VBA code using file objects to go into a folder, search for particular files (CSV) that meet certain criteria (contain "HR" in filename and created within specified date range), and copy/paste information out of that file into a master file. The master file is typically a compilation of 250+ workbooks.

The macro works as it should, but it takes about 12 minutes to run, which is a bit excessive. I believe it takes so long to run because it is indexing a folder with 30,000+ files in it.

I've copied the relevant lines of my code below, if anyone is aware of any modifications I could make that would decrease the duration of my macro, I would really appreciate it. I'm relatively new to VBA and coding in general, so I'm learning as I go with these sorts of things! Thanks!

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim objFile As file
Dim fileDate As Date
Dim firstDate As Date
Dim secondDate As Date

'Defining the user-input variables
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
firstDate = Cells(2, "E").Value
secondDate = Cells(3, "E").Value

'FilePath to information, defining file objects
FilePath = "\\SRV-1\process\DUMP\"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FilePath)

'Going through Dump folder and finding high resolution files created within the date range
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        'Checking to see if the file contains the string "HR", indicating high resolution.
        If InStr(1, objFile.Name, "HR") Then GoTo Line1 Else GoTo Line3

Line1:
        'Storing the file as a variable and checking its creation date
        FileName = objFile.Name
        OpenFile = FilePath & FileName
        fileDate = FileDateTime(OpenFile)

        'Checking to see if the file was created between the user input master roll start/end dates
        If firstDate < fileDate And secondDate > fileDate Then GoTo Line2 Else GoTo Line3

Line2:
    Do stuff: open dump workbook, copy/pase certain range into main workbook, close dump workbook, next objFile

Line3:
    Next objFile
```

Comment: If the code works, then this question is off-topic for StackOverflow. You would be better off asking at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you comment out the "do stuff" section, how long does it take?

Comment: Using `FileSystemObject` is almost always (?always?) going to be slower than a `DIR` loop.

Comment: Also, what does your `FileDateAndTime` function do? Can you include that code?

Comment: Your `GoTo` statements are unnecessary (not to mention that using such GoTo statements is not a good practice, generally). A better coding style would use `If/End If` or other conditional expressions to control flow, using GoTo only as a last resort if it cannot be avoided.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad my apologies, I'll post this over in CodeReview later, I'm new to these sites.

Comment: @DavidZemens I wasn't able to use a DIR loop because it reset itself every time my loop restarted, I came across a post discussing the same issue, and they were able to resolve it by using the FileSystemObject.

The FileDateTime function checks the file's creation date to see if it falls between two user defined points in time. I believe the code you're looking for is right beneath "Line1" in the code above. If the file meets the creation date time, it copies/pastes the information in that file, else goes to the next loop.

Comment: a loop doesn't "restart", so I'm not sure I understand the problem, but in any case it's just a suggestion that Dir is MUCH faster than FSO. you marry ultimately need FSO to get the date time value of the file, though.

Comment: As for the GoTo statements, I'm going to chalk that up to inexperience with coding. I understand GoTo better in my head, but perhaps I ought to look more into using If/End If.

Comment: @TimWilliams commenting out the "do stuff" section makes the file take about 9 minutes instead of 12, meaning the bulk of the macro occurs when looking up/searching through the large dump folder

Comment: I posted an updated solution, this can be done without using `FileSystemObject` at all, which should improve your performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to show *some* improvement, considering the ratio of HR files to total files (250 / 30,000).

### Using `Dir` Function, Minimize reliance on `FileSystemObject`

The idea here is to use the `Dir` function first to get a list of all file names that contain the "HR" substring, and only use the `FileSystemObject` against those files to get the timestamp information -- there's no use incurring the overhead of FSO on *every* file in that directory.

Then, we process *only* those files which match the "HR" criteria:

```
Sub usingDir()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim filesToProcess As New Collection
Dim item As Variant
Dim fileDate As Date
Dim firstDate As Date
Dim secondDate As Date

'Defining the user-input variables
firstDate = Cells(2, "E").Value
secondDate = Cells(3, "E").Value
folderPath = "\\SRV-1\process\DUMP\"

' Gets a collection of files matching the "HR" criteria
fileName = Dir(folderPath)
Do While Not fileName = ""
    If InStr(fileName, "HR") > 0 Then
        'Only processing files with "HR"
        filesToProcess.Add (folderPath & fileName)
    End If
    fileName = Dir
Loop

'Now we deal only with the "HR" files:
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each item In filesToProcess
        ' Check the date last modified
        fileDate = .GetFile(item).DateLastModified ' modify as needed
        If firstDate < fileDate And secondDate > fileDate Then
            '
            '
            Debug.Print item
            'your code to Do Stuff goes here
            '
            '
            '
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

### UPDATE: Without Using the `FileSystemObject`

This was nagging at me, and I figured there must be a way to get the timestamp information *without* relying on `FileSystemObject`. There is. We'll still use `Dir` to traverse the files, but now we'll eliminate any reference to `FileSystemObject` and replace with some fancy WinAPI function calls. Check out Chip Pearson's article [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FileTimes.htm) and download the [.bas modules](http://www.cpearson.com/Zips/modGetSetFileTimes.zip). You'll need the following two files imported to your VBProject:

- modGetSetFileTimes
- modTimeConversionFunctions

And then you can do something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub withoutFSO()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim filesToProcess As New Collection
Dim item As Variant
Dim fileDate As Date
Dim firstDate As Date
Dim secondDate As Date

'Defining the user-input variables
firstDate = Cells(2, "E").Value
secondDate = Cells(3, "E").Value
folderPath = "\\Your\Path"

' Gets a collection of files matching the "HR" criteria and our Date range
FileName = Dir(folderPath)
Do While Not FileName = ""
    'Only processing files with "HR"
    If InStr(FileName, "HR") > 0 Then
        ' Only process files that meet our date criteria
        fileDate = CDate(modGetSetFileTimes.GetFileDateTime(CStr(item), FileDateLastModified))
        If firstDate < fileDate And secondDate > fileDate Then
            filesToProcess.Add (folderPath & FileName)
        End If
    End If
    FileName = Dir
Loop

'Now we deal only with the matching files:
For Each item In filesToProcess
    Debug.Print item
    Debug.Print fileDate
    'your code to Do Stuff goes here
    '
    '
    '
Next
End Sub
```

This should be an improvement even over my original answer, and, if combined with a more efficient manner of retrieving data (i.e., using ADO instead of `Workbooks.Open`, if possible) then you should be very optimized.

Comment: thanks for this answer! When I get some free time later this week, I'm going to give this a shot, I believe this is what I'm looking for. I'll be sure to let you know how it works!

Comment: I also really appreciate that you included articles for additional reading. I'm excited to dive into them and learn more!

Comment: I was able to use your first batch of code to greatly reduce the time it takes to run my macro (from 12 minutes to 3 minutes!) I wasn't able to figure out how to utilize the WinAPI function calls, it seemed as though my variables were being lost between the different modules (filePath turned into null when it went to the first of Pearson's modules). I tried defining all my variables and modules as public to no success. However, I'm more than satisfied with the result your first idea gave me. Thanks so much!

Comment: @YarHarr try wrapping `filePath` in the `Cstr` function. Sometimes I've also noticed strings passing as empty to API calls or when sent over COM, etc., but if you wrap it in the `CStr` function, that might fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Power Query -- it's a Microsoft add-in for Excel versions 2012 & 2013, and built-in to 2016.  Setting up PQ to do this will be amazingly fast, and the 'script' is reusable! No VBA needed.

You can search and combine the multiple files on the specified criteria, but then merge or append to the new/master file, too. For efficiency, rather than processing each file individually, might I  suggest gathering up all the data files (by your criteria), combining them to one table, then use the new table to merge/append to the new/master

Hope this helps...

Comment: That's a pretty neat tool! Thanks for sharing, I'll have to investigate it some more. I need to make these macros/tools as simple as possible so that they can be run on a regular basis (15 times per day) by people that are not very good with using computers. I'll see if I can't figure out how to connect Power Query up to a button that does everything for the user. Thanks again!

Comment: Post back at me when you know how to attach the PQ query to a button, please.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using the `Dir` function instead of `FileSystemObject`, if you cannot automate PowerQuery, and all you need is the data and not the formatting, consider making a direct data connection to the source workbooks using ADODB.

Add a reference to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library** (via **Tools** -> **References...**). There may be versions other than 6.1; choose the highest.

Then you can use something like the following code:

```
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim filepath As Variant
For Each filepath In filesToProcess
    ' Check the date last modified
    fileDate = fso.GetFile(item).DateLastModified ' modify as needed
    If firstDate < fileDate And secondDate > fileDate Then

        Dim connectionString As String
        connectionString = _
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""

        Dim worksheetName As String
        worksheetName = "Sheet1"
        ' There can be multiple worksheets per workbook.
        ' If you are only interested in one worksheet per workbook, then fill in worksheetName somehow
        ' Otherwise, you will probably need an inner loop to iterate over all the worksheets

        Dim sql As String
        sql = _
            "SELECT * " & _
            "FROM [" & worksheetName & "$]"

        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.Open sql, connectionString

        destinationWorksheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
Next
```

Comment: +1 for ADO. It was nagging at me that OP will need FSO to get the timestamp information, though, but I found another way using some WinAPI calls. Combining these approaches should greatly improve the performance :)

Comment: Thanks for the information, Zev! I've not used ActiveX Data Objects before, I will pursue this as a potential solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It took a long time because for each interation you pass the information to the main worksheet.

In this case is better use a multidimensional array to keep the information and in the end of the process you pass the the array info in the main worksheet.

I dont know what information you get in each worksheet, soo i cant create an didatical example for you.

Comment: Thank you for the information, skulden. I'm not too familiar with multidimensional arrays, but I will pursue them further if the above two responses aren't able to increase the efficiency of this code. Thanks again!