# VBA Getting run-time error (5) when trying to Delete existing file

Tags: vba, delete-file, filesystemobject

I am getting a run-time error invalid procedure (error # 5) on this line:

```
afiles(countoflines).Delete True
```

I can't understand why. The save copy to the path works fine, and the assignation of the FSO to the folder files works , but I can't delete the 'x'th indexed item in the folder. Can someone assist with this?
Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim aFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim aFolder As Object
Dim aFiles As Object

Set aFolder = aFSO.GetFolder("R:\Groups\Finance\Ops Finance\Reporting\F18 Cost Analysis\Standard Costing\Std Cost Variances\Variance Master Back-Ups\")
If aFolder Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Directory not found!", vbExclamation: Exit Sub

Set aFiles = aFolder.Files

Application.StatusBar = "Saving back up copy"

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs aFolder.Path & "\" & _
VBA.Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", "") & "_copy_" & _
VBA.Format$(Now, "m-d-yyyy hhmmss AM/PM") & ".xlsm"

Call CleanUpArchive(aFolder, aFolder.Path & Chr(92), aFiles.Count)

Set aFolder = Nothing
Set aFSO = Nothing

End Sub



'Cleans up archive file by deleting the 11th file (oldest copy)
Private Function CleanUpArchive(Folder As Object, Path As String, _
CountofFiles As Integer)

Dim aFiles As Scripting.Files
Set aFiles = Folder.Files

If CountofFiles > 10 Then
aFiles(CountofFiles).Delete True
End If

Set aFiles = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Can you try using the `Kill` statement against the full path, e.g.: `Kill "c:\path\to\file.txt"`?

Comment: I'm also not certain that Files(Files.Count) represents the "last" or most recent file in the directory.

Comment: Thanks David Zemens. Kill didn't work either. maybe it's the object

Comment: Can you update your question to include your use of `Kill` statement, and also show what is the value of the path that you're passing to that statement? This will fail if the file is locked/in-use.

Comment: May have to declare a variant to loop through items and kill based on a condition

Comment: Yes, you probably need a different way of identifying which file to delete. Then, assuming file is not locked, you should be able to `Kill` it.

Comment: If you're keen to re-factor the code, you can most likely do this without FileSystemObject. See [this recent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601354/how-to-traverse-files-conditionally-faster-than-using-filesystemobject/51602533#51602533) which explains how to use `Dir` function to traverse the files, and then uses some WinAPI calls to ascertain the DateLastModified (I think you can modify that to DateCreated as well).

Answer (score 0):

Untested, written on mobile. The below is not that different from your code, but might do what you need.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim folderPath as string
folderPath = dir$("R:\Groups\Finance\Ops Finance\Reporting\F18 Cost Analysis\Standard Costing\Std Cost Variances\Variance Master Back-Ups\", vbdirectory)

If Len(folderPath) = 0 then
Msgbox("Could not locate folder")
Exit sub
Elseif strcomp(right(folderPath, 1),"\", vbbinarycompare) <> 0 then ' this might be unnecessary, depends if dir() on vbdirectory returns \ at end or not, cannot remember or test'
folderPath = folderPath & "\"
End if

Dim filenames() as string
Redim filenames(1 to 2, 1 to 1000) ' 1000 = magic number, change if needed.'

Dim fileIndex as long

Dim filename as string
Filename = dir$(folderPath & "*")

Do until Len(filename) = 0

Fileindex = fileindex +1
Filename(1, fileindex) = folderPath & filename
Filenames(2, fileindex) = filedatetime(Filename(1, fileindex))
Filename = dir$()

Loop

Redim preserve filenames(1 to 2, 1 to fileindex)

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs folderPath & _
VBA.Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", "_copy_" & _
VBA.Format$(Now, "m-d-yyyy hhmmss AM/PM") & ".xlsm")

Dim Oldest as Date
Dim OldestIndex as long

Oldest = filenames(2,1) ' Initialise with first value'

' Might be better to store below in dictionary -- or any key-value/associative structure. But should work nonetheless.'
For fileindex = lbound(filenames,2) to ubound(filenames,2)
If filenames(2, fileindex) < oldest then
Oldest = filenames(2, fileindex)
OldestIndex = fileindex
End if
Next fileindex

Dim fileIsOpen as Boolean

On error resume next
Open filenames(1, OldestIndex) For Input Lock Read As #1
fileIsOpen = err.number <> 0
On error goto 0
Close #1

If fileIsOpen then
msgbox("Attempted to delete file at:" & filenames(1, OldestIndex) & " but file may be open elsewhere or by another user.")
Exit sub
Else
' In theory, the file could go from not-in-use to in-use between the check above and the delete below. Might be better just to try to kill without checking but with on error resume, and then checking if file still exists or is open.'
Kill filenames(1, OldestIndex)
End if

End sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this it looks like a good solution. However, I've utilized the Dir() function as David Zemens mentioned and did a Kill based on comparing current date and date created for each date and deleting ones older than 'x' days. Thanks though.